# "EEException: Image.reduceRegions: Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform." not accepting either

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

Question: Why won't image reduce region accept either a scale or a reprojection, in most of my cases but not all.

Context: I'm trying to find if a landsat pixel has any cloud (based on SimpleCloudScore) and then if no cloud I will extract the other bands to csv, I know this is intensive and slow but will only be done for a few select pixels. The errors may be something to do with the region being a point but it has worked for some of the points.

```
def arethereclouds(image):
    image_cloud = image.select('cloud')
    total_cloud = image_cloud.reduceRegion(**{
        'reducer': ee.Reducer.sum(), 
        'geometry': eefeature_point,
        'maxPixels': 100000,
        'scale': 30,
        
    })
    im = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(total_cloud.get('cloud')).gt(1), ee.Image.constant(-999).rename('extraction_band'), image)
    return im
```

I started with the error "EEException: Image.reduceRegions: The default WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations. Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform." **for some, not all of the features I've tried**

So I added

```
 'crs': 'EPSG:3857' , 
 'crsTransform':[1,0,0,0,1,0]
```

to the reducer, resulting in the error "EEException: ImageCollection.toBands: Error in map(ID=LC08_186029_20130505):
Image.reduceRegion: Cannot specify both crsTransform and scale."

But when I remove scale from the reducer, we go the full circle back to the original EEexception?

*Efforts to fix it I've tried:*

- adding a buffer to the feature to see if it was some issue there
- different EPSGs
- different scales

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete, runnable example that completes without error. If you're getting errors with different input, the problem might be there. But you haven't provided any information on it.

```
import ee

ee.Initialize()

image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_194053_20201124').select(['B1'], ['cloud'])
    
eefeature_point = image.geometry().centroid()

def arethereclouds(image):
    image_cloud = image.select('cloud')
    total_cloud = image_cloud.reduceRegion(
        reducer=ee.Reducer.sum(), 
        geometry=eefeature_point,
        maxPixels=100000, 
        scale=30    
    )
    im = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(total_cloud.get('cloud')).gt(1), ee.Image.constant(-999).rename('extraction_band'), image)
    return im 

arethereclouds(image).getInfo()
```

This outputs

```
{'type': 'Image',
 'bands': [{'id': 'extraction_band',
   'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType',
    'precision': 'int',
    'min': -999,
    'max': -999},
   'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
   'crs_transform': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still results in the same errors.

Comment: I updated my answer.